# What is the best way to dictate to a repository which result object properties to populate and leave the others null?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository

I am working on a Domain Driven Design project and I have the following problem.

I am trying to create a repository that returns a list of objects. The objects have 15 - 20 properties and according to usage I need each time a few of them. Returning full populated objects will cost during population, serialization - deserialization. What is the optimal way to dictate to the repository (perhaps using a parameter in the repository Find method) which properties to populate and leave the others null?

Splitting the object to thinner ones is not an option.

One solution that I thought is passing to the repository an instance of the object (as a blueprint) with null values to the properties that I don't want. The repository will read these values and in the result list it will populate only the non null properties accordingly.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: "Splitting the object to thinner ones is not an option." - Why?

Comment: There are many property subsets that are needed and that would require a different repository find method for each thinner object.

Comment: I recommend that you review your aggregate boundary. If you have low cohesion between groups of properties maybe you should split the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested solution sounds similar to the "query by example" pattern that used to be common with object databases. It suffers from the same drawback: it requires query code to know how to construct valid domain objects, which means that as your domain objects evolve you may need to make unnecessary changes to your query code simply to keep validation code happy, particularly when additional validation rules are added.

There are a number of approaches that don't have the issue. If you're using reflection, then simply providing a list of names of fields to include or exclude is one approach. Or you could define valid subsets in the repository and use an enumeration to select one.  You could also use annotations to allow subsets to be defined in the domain objects themselves, if your language supports that.